# validation of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, validation, loops, foreach

I am creating a validation class and am having trouble mounting the case...
**$rule** and **$form** accept array and here is the problem.
Could only validate effectively using 4 loops: foreach + foreach + foreach + foreach
Someone could tell if there is another way without using many loops?

```
$ rule = array(
         'alias.1' => array('required' => 1),
         'alias.2' => array('required' => 1, 'case' => 'upper'),
         );

$ form = array(
         'alias.1' => array('first_name', 'last_name'),
         'alias.2' => 'my city'
         );
```

No need to attach an example, just an idea to help solve my problem.
Thank you

Comment: its be better if you add what if have done in that you said in your post.

Comment: I have nothing important, just a sequence of 4 loops

Comment: an array_walk with filter_var would be a great fit here

Comment: and where are the values, I'm sorry but I couldn't guess wither `first_name` is a value to be validated or just the name of the variable?

Comment: first_name, last_name fictitious values ​​are shaped array of field alias.1 - only example

Comment: Your concept isn't well. Quick view: you have your keys in `$rules` array as a declaration of rule for some field. Thus, to apply this rule, that field must present in validated array. And if so, there's no need in `required` condition (i.e. your field is required simply because it exists in `$rules` array, and, therefore, that restriction is redundant)